Jetbrain Rider IDE File Open Actions
In Jetbrains Rider IDE, when I do left click, I get a message "File Open Actions. Nothing here". Please find attached screenshot.

I have tried mutliple keymap settings but still unable to figure this out.
Also I'm unable to open the file from the left navigation menu which opens in the file in edit mode on the right pane. Tried multiple things and this is still an issue. Can somebody help here ?

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER You might get assistance from there.

It looks like u have Set a HotKey for FileWatchers. You might check on that.
Go to your Settings (CTRL + ALT + S) > Keymap and search for File Watchers. U might have set an Hotkey there by accident. Otherwise, check on your Plugins, maybe some Plugin might create your Problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
